# To Understand .Net Configuration files

Tags: .net

Would like to explore the .Net Configuration (web.config & machine.config..), please help me by providing the URLs which can help me on this.

Thanks!
Karthikeyan

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309586/resources-for-understanding-web-config-essentials

Comment: www.google.com is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

These three articles by Jon Rista cover .NET Configuration in a lot of detail:

[Unraveling the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx)

[Decoding the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration2.aspx)

[Cracking the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx)